# VB FTP code works in Debug (F10) but not when run or F5

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, shell, ftp

I need to FTP a local file to Mainframe and have written the below script to create a local Batch text file using streamwriter and then use this file with the ftp -s: command to run it.

Here is the code.

```
 Shared Sub TestFTP()

    '  BP DEFINED INPUTS ANDF OUTPUTS

    'Inputs
    Dim hostname As String
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim mainfile As String
    Dim localfile As String

    'Outputs
    Dim success As Boolean
    Dim message As String

    '-------------
    'Test DATA
    '-------------

    hostname = "XXIBM2"
    username = "USER1"
    password = "XXX1234"
    mainfile = "XXTSO.USER1.TEST2"
    localfile = "D:\TestFTP.txt"

    '=============================BP Code========================
    Try
        Dim localPath As String = "C:\BPFTP"
        Dim isExists As Boolean = System.IO.Directory.Exists(localPath)

        If (isExists = False) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath)
        End If

        ' Open StreamWriter And create batch file

        Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(localPath + "\\FTP.txt")

            writer.WriteLine("open " + hostname)
            writer.WriteLine(username)
            writer.WriteLine(password)
            writer.WriteLine("put " + localfile + " '" + mainfile + "'")
            writer.WriteLine("bye")
            writer.WriteLine("exit")
        End Using

        ' Perform FTP

        Interaction.Shell("ftp -n -s:C:\BPFTP\FTP.txt") 

        ' Delete batch file

        System.IO.File.Delete("C:\\BPFTP\\FTP.txt")
        success = True

    Catch e As Exception

        success = False
        message = e.Message

    End Try


End Sub
```

If I run the code using F5 the file does not appear on the mainframe.

If I set a breakpoing at the Shell command and run the code (f5) to here and then F5 to the end the file does not get FTPd to the mainframe.

HOWEVER.

If I run the code to the breakpoint and then simply 'Step Over' the Shell command line using F10 then the file successfully FTPs to the mainframe.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I have admin rights.  Jimmy Smith provided a solution to the problem below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run in debug mode, you are forcing a synchronous operation, you need to tell shell and your ftp application to wait in order to completely send the file.

```
Interaction.Shell("ftp -n -s:C:\BPFTP\FTP.txt", AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus, True, 30000)
```

[See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell(v=vs.110).aspx)

This will force it to wait 30 seconds before continuing, if you set it to -1 it waits forever which can cause undesirable behavior.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. That works apart from that the timeout is in milliseconds not seconds so I had to change this to 1000 to give me 1 second.  It worked fine then.

Comment: Corrected my answer.  Your issue was a tricky one that I've had myself with other processes I had to shell.